# How to remove a placeable from compose custom layout

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I'm playing around testing with SubcomposeLayout and I not understanding a behavior when "remove" a placeable from the `layout()`. Let me show the code

```kotlin
@Composable
fun ExpandItem(
    top: @Composable () -> Unit,
    bottom: @Composable () -> Unit,
    expanded: Boolean,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
) {
    SubcomposeLayout(modifier = modifier) { constraints ->
        val topPlaceable = subcompose(ExpandedItemSlot.TOP, top).map { measurable ->
            measurable.measure(constraints)
        }.first()

        val bottomPlaceable = subcompose(ExpandedItemSlot.BOTTOM, bottom).map { measurable ->
            measurable.measure(constraints)
        }.first()

        val width = maxOf(topPlaceable.width, bottomPlaceable.width)
        val totalHeight = topPlaceable.height + bottomPlaceable.height

        val height = if(expanded) totalHeight else topPlaceable.height

        layout(width, height) {
            topPlaceable.placeRelative(0, 0)
            if (expanded) {
                bottomPlaceable.placeRelative(0, topPlaceable.height)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And I using like

```kotlin
var expanded by remember {
    mutableStateOf(false)
}
ExpandItem(
    modifier = Modifier
        .clickable {
        expanded = !expanded
    },
    top = {
        Text("top")
    },
    bottom = {
        Column {
            Text("bottom1")
            Text("bottom2")
            Text("bottom3")
        }
    },
    expanded = expanded
)
```

When I check the component tree on layout inspector for the first time, It's show the component as expected

[image: closed composable]

And then when I click to expand

[image: expanded composable]

But if I close the composable again, the `bottom` still shows on component tree

[image: closed composable again]

Why this happen? There is a way to actually remove this `bottom` composable when I set the `expanded` to false?

Thanks!